# Prove $f'(0)=0$, if $|f(x)|≤x^2$

Tags: derivatives

Let $f:(-a,a) \longrightarrow R$, $a>0$.

Such that 
$$
|f(x)|≤x^2
$$

What I did was taking out the module bars so I get $-x^2≤f(x)≤x^2$ and I see that at $x=0$ the function must be zero.

I see why f'(0) must equal zero at that point,  but I have no idea on how to prove it.

Comment: @barto your function **is** differentiable at zero!

Comment: @barto Again: false.

Comment: So what? It seems to me you cannot see that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=0$ without *any* further assumptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inequality implies $f(0) = 0$. Further, $\left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| \le |x|$ for all $x\neq 0$. Taking the limit as $x\to 0$, we obtain $|f'(0)| \le 0$. Thus $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: Why assume that $f'(0)$ exists? Doesn't that follow from the estimate $\left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| \le |x|$ ?

Comment: The existence of $f'(0)$ is ensured by that same inequality.

Comment: Indeed. In fact one deduces _first_ that $\lim_{x\to0}|\frac{f(x)}x|$ exists and equals $0$; therefore $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}x$ exists and equals $0$.

Comment: How do you obtain $|f'(0)|\leq 0$ with that limit?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD from $\lim_{x\to 0} \left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| \le \lim_{x\to 0} |x|$. The left hand side is $|f'(0)|$, and the right hand side is $0$.